# Can I clone list of repositories from GitHub and run plagiarism check

Tags: copyleaks-api

Is it possible to clone a list of repos from GitHub and run a plagiarism check on them?

Example:

1. A file with the list of GitHub repo (let's say 10) - this file can be called "big"
2. A file with the list of GitHub repo (let's say 2) - this file can be called "small"

I want to compare "small" against "big".

So I need to clone all repo links in the "big" file and also clone all repo in the "small" file and then compare and return links with the plagiarized cases.

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is way to generic. I would suggest you try to code something first and ask if you run against any issues. We don't even know what programming language you want to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this documentation page - [Cross plagiarism compare of multiple files](https://api.copyleaks.com/documentation/v3/activities/cross-compare-multiple-files).

Quick summarization: you have to use Copyleaks database in order to index all the files from GitHub repository 1. Than you will have to scan GitHub repository 2 files against your database.